# Why does this follow from the triangle inequality?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Proving that differentiability implies continuity.

[image: differentiability implies continuity]

Comment: which book is this from? thanks.

Comment: @Tim http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Classical-Analysis-2nd-Edition/dp/0716721058

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\lvert a \rvert = \lvert a-b+b \rvert  \leq \lvert a-b\rvert +  \lvert b\rvert$ by the triangle inequality,so that $\lvert a-b \rvert \geq \lvert a\rvert -  \lvert b\rvert$.

Here, they use this with $a= f(x_0+\Delta x) - f(x_0)$ and $b=f^\prime(x_0)\Delta x$:

$$
\lvert a - b\rvert \leq \varepsilon  \lvert  \Delta x\rvert
$$
implies 
$$
\lvert a\rvert - \lvert b\rvert \leq \varepsilon  \lvert  \Delta x\rvert
$$
so that
$$
\lvert a\rvert  \leq \varepsilon  \lvert  \Delta x\rvert + \lvert b\rvert.
$$